# CodeIgniter: Placement of .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm trying to configure CodeIgniter and remove `index.php` from the URL . I placed my `.htaccess` file with the applications folder and tried various codes posted by users. But it didn't work and `index.php` is still there. Initially the file was with the `config` folder. Can Anyone help me with this?

All suggestions are welcomed....
Thanks in advance...

Comment: what do you mean by index.php still there? Does it mean it does not work without index.php?

Comment: yes, it is not working without `index.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your .htaccess file at your root directory not Inside the application folder.

Keep following lines inside your .htaccess file and keep it at your root directory.It should work with and without index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to application/config/config.php and edit next:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

to:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

If this doesn't work please post your .htaccess file content.

Answer (score 0):

The only .htaccess you should edit is the one placed in your root directory  of your website (or wherever your index.php file is).

your .htaccess should contain :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Also in your config.php set $config['index_page'] to empty :

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Take a look at the the documentation : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /projects/hc/homecare/trunk/homecare 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|system)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projects/hc/homecare/trunk/homecare/index.php?/$1 [L]
```